# RAW Image processing in Python

Tags: python, image, dng, dcraw

Are there any Pythonic solutions to reading and processing RAW images. Even if it's simply accessing a raw photo file (eg. cr2 or dng) and then outputting it as a jpeg.

Ideally a dcraw bindings for python, but anything else that can accomplish the came would be sufficient as well.

Answer (score 29):

A while ago I wrote a libraw/dcraw wrapper called [rawpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rawpy). It is quite easy to use:

```
import rawpy
import imageio

raw = rawpy.imread('image.nef')
rgb = raw.postprocess()
imageio.imsave('default.tiff', rgb)
```

It works natively with numpy arrays and supports a lot of options, including direct access to the unprocessed Bayer data.

Comment: Is it possible to import raw and export raw?

Answer (score 8):

[**ImageMagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org/) supports [most RAW formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) and provides [Python bindings](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#python).

As for dcraw bindings for Python: dcraw is written in C, so you can access it through [`ctypes` module](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to convert a canon CR2 image to a friendly format with [rawkit](https://github.com/photoshell/rawkit), that works with its current implementation:

```
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image
from rawkit.raw import Raw

filename = '/path/to/your/image.cr2'
raw_image = Raw(filename)
buffered_image = np.array(raw_image.to_buffer())
image = Image.frombytes('RGB', (raw_image.metadata.width, raw_image.metadata.height), buffered_image)
image.save('/path/to/your/new/image.png', format='png')
```

Using a numpy array is not very elegant here but at least it works, I could not figure how to use PIL constructors to achieve the same.

Comment: You are saving jpeg format to a file with png extension.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the typo.

Comment: rawkit does not support libraw 0.19+ which is now Ubuntu default version...

Answer (score 1):

Try http://libopenraw.freedesktop.org/wiki/GettingTheCode

Git repo:
git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/libopenraw.git

There is a python directory in the source tree. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how extensive the RAW support in Python Imaging Library (PIL http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) is, but you may want to check that out.

Otherwise, you could just call dcraw directly since it already solves this problem nicely.

Comment: PIL doesn't do RAWs (at least, not CR2's or DCR's).

Answer (score 0):

I found this: https://gitorious.org/dcraw-thumbnailer/mainline/blobs/master/dcraw-thumbnailer

It calls dcraw as a process from python and converts it to a PIL object.