# Reading a RAW image (.CR2) using numpy.fromfile

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, numpy

I am trying to read a raw image in .CR2 format ("Canon Raw format"). I wanted to do it with opencv initially but could not get it to work so I tried doing it with a numpy function:

```
img = np.fromfile('IMG.CR2', "uint16")
```

The camera is a canon EOS t5 18MP DSLR.
If I run `img.size` it return `10105415` which seems too small for an 18 MP camera.

My first question, is using `np.fromfile()` a valid approach?

Secondly, would you recommend any other python libraries to do the same process in an easier way/more efficient? I have openCV installed so if it could be done there, that would be great (I still want to store it as a numpy array).

Comment: Why posting duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648371/reading-data-from-cr2-raw-image-using-opencv-and-python

Comment: that duplicate no longer exists

Answer (score 2):

Canon RAW format is not just a blob of data, it has some metadata which you need to parse. Luckily, others have already implemented some python parsers.

[RAW Image processing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422050/raw-image-processing-in-python)

After using one of the suggested solutions you can load the data into numpy array.