# What is the simplest way to extract the jpeg preview from a Nikon raw file with python?

Tags: python, image, jpeg

I'm looking for the simplest way to extract the embedded jpg preview from a Nikon raw file (.nef) in Python 2.7. How should I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RAW Image processing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422050/raw-image-processing-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Although I have not been able to test it, it may work with [`rawpy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rawpy) to read the `.nef` file and [`imageio`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imageio) to save it as `jpg`:

```
import rawpy
import imageio

path = 'image.nef'
with rawpy.imread(path) as raw:
    rgb = raw.postprocess()
imageio.imsave('default.jpg', rgb)
```